# Can not start the Perimeter81

Tags: windows-10

Whenever I try to run the Perimeter81 app, I wait for 90 seconds and after that I am getting the following error:

> Perimiter81 windows service did not start in time. 
> Please click on "Fix" to attempt the fix or close the popup to cancel login.

I click on the `Fix` button, wait for 40 more seconds and get exactly the same error. And this cycle repeats.

I tried to restart my laptop and still it did not help.

Any ideas of what may be wrong here?

[image]

Comment: I'd simply contact their support honestly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get this instruction from support team
Here are the instructions I believe will fix the issue for your device

1. Make sure P81 client is uninstalled: Select Start, then select Settings > Apps > Apps & features.
   ﻿Select the app you want to remove, and then select Uninstall.
   ﻿
   ﻿2. Please uninstall .Net 6 on your system
   ﻿
   ﻿After Perimeter81 is running correctly you may install .Net 6 again.
   ﻿
2. Install .net 5 via this [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-5.0.403-windows-x64-installer) (SDK).
   ﻿
3. Restart the device
   ﻿
4. Install p81 client (at this point the machine installs the service via dotnet). To install the client please use this [link](https://support.perimeter81.com/v1/docs/en/downloading-the-agent).
   Also please make sure you follow the steps in numerical order. These files might be large to download but I think this should solve the issues.